# Rest url parameter with slashes

Tags: c#, rest

I have a simple rest endpoint

`myapi/documents/<doc title>/sections`

And yes, i need the `doc title` there. It should be the `id`, i know, but its has been decided thats not gonna be the ID.

But then i have a document title that's
`<script>alert("wololo");</script>`

When this gets on my URL, surely it wont work. I'm calling this from a c# backend (one backend calling other backend)

`Post(_httpClient, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documentType), new Uri(_url + "/api/documents/"+title+ "/sections"));`

What would be a good way of solving this ?

Comment: Use `Uri.EscapeDataString(title)` to escape data which should go into the URL. In your case it would return `%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22wololo%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E`.

Comment: it seems it still wont work on path (if using like a get parameter, it works, but not as a path) :(

Comment: What do you mean it still wont work? does the string get escaped or is it not passing the correct value? Please add your new code and show what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

An uri "/documents/foo/bar/sections" is equal to "/documents/foo%2Fbar/sections".
So if you have slashes in your title you need to find a way to encode and decode your title in the URL if your application cannot make the routing to the resource if the title contains a slash. You could e.g. replace slahes with double hyphens (--) or similar.

Comment: Both URI’s are not equal as you can’t interchange `/` (which is a delimiter) and `%2f` (which is an encoded character and by definition (RFC 3986) never a delimiter). That’s the whole point of using percent encoding: to encode characters outside the supported charset and escape characters which are usually used as delimiters. If you go to any website and replace the slash with its percent encoding you very likely will not get the same resource, but rather an error.

Comment: Sorry ckuri, but you aren't correct. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-6 for the normalization and comparision rules. Reading it carefully will show you that both URI's are equal. If you replace the slash by it's percent encoding you must get the same ressource, if you get an error then the implementation of the webservice is broken.

Comment: Section 6.2.2.2. writes "These URIs should be normalized by decoding any percent-encoded octet that corresponds to an unreserved character, as described in Section 2.3." and in section 2.3 defines unreserved characters as "ALPHA (%41-%5A and %61-%7A), DIGIT (%30-%39), hyphen (%2D), period (%2E), underscore (%5F), or tilde (%7E)". The slash or any other delimeter is not an _unreserved character_ and thus not equal to their percent-encodings.

Comment: Also section 2.1 writes "A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the component." There wouldn't be any point to percent-encode delimeters if their encoded (and thus escaped) form is still equal to their unencoded form.